# Minecraft 1.10.2 Chest disappearing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I had been playing Minecraft 1.10.2 for a while, and night started to come, so I dug into the ground to make a makeshift home. I had a chest, a crafting table, and a furnace all in a 3×3×3 room with a torch. Then I saved and closed the game, and before I left I put everything but a stone pockaxe, shovel, axe and sword, all in that order, along with 4 pieces of steak, into a chest. Then I came back this morning to find my entire chest, along with the items, is gone. Nothing else changed though. Anyone know why this happened?

Comment: Is this SMP or is this single player?

Comment: I am assuming you are in Single player because you said you "saved" and then closed the game?

Comment: I may seem like a madman, but it might be the work of herobrine...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, depends on what you are playing on. Single player or multiplayer. If its multiplayer, One of the problems that might be the game failed to load completely or someone else stole it. If it is single player, something might have glitched. I'm not a minecraft expert, but that's my suggestion

Comment: If you don't have a source and you aren't sure of your answer, it is better to just leave a comment on the question with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be a glitch because you have version 1.10 instead of 1.14 Java or 1.12 Bedrock. Try updating the game. If it costs money, I don't know how to fix it other than updating. Hope this helps!